# animation canvas drawing with transparent background

Tags: android, android-canvas

i have an object that moves on the screen and the background is transparent
so the problem that is created is that the object is multply every frame is moves
because you can see the other canvases under this canvas

(the animation is a loop that every loop it creates a new canvas and draws on it the object)
here is the code:

```
while(isRunning){
        Canvas c=null;

        try{
            c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (this.getHolder()) {
                this.onDraw(c);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        finally{
            if(c!=null){
                this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

        }
    }
```

here is the onDraw:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    object.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

i need the background to be transparent because i have a background in the xml.
before i decided the background to be transparent i made it colored so it colored over the other canvases every loop, then there wasn't any problem.

how do i fix this problem?

Comment: "it creates a new canvas" how does it do that?

Comment: i edited and added the code

Comment: not sure, but try canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

Comment: it doesn't recognize the PorterDuff

Comment: what? what doesnt recognize?

Comment: the eclipse,:"PorterDuff cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: because it is not **import** ed

Comment: alright it works partly, there is a bug i am not sure it's related to this, so Tnx for help